# Laravel livewire render issue

Tags: laravel, laravel-livewire

Evening all.

I am trying to achieve a live search of my Employee model.

So I have copied this livewire tutorial but when i render the page i get this error?
https://www.twilio.com/blog/build-live-search-box-laravel-livewire-mysql

```
SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1191 Can't find FULLTEXT index matching the column list (SQL: select count(*) as aggregate from `employees` where MATCH (id) AGAINST ( IN BOOLEAN MODE) and `employees`.`archived_at` is null) (View: /Users/*/Sites/*/resources/views/partials/tenders/search-modal.blade.php)
```

here is my Search trait

```
<?php

namespace App\Models;

trait Search
{
    private function buildWildCards($term) {
        if ($term == "") {
            return $term;
        }

        // Strip MySQL reserved symbols
        $reservedSymbols = ['-', '+', '<', '>', '@', '(', ')', '~'];
        $term = str_replace($reservedSymbols, '', $term);

        $words = explode(' ', $term);
        foreach($words as $idx => $word) {
            // Add operators so we can leverage the boolean mode of
            // fulltext indices.
            $words[$idx] = "+" . $word . "*";
        }
        $term = implode(' ', $words);
        return $term;
    }

    protected function scopeSearch($query, $term) {
        $columns = implode(',', $this->searchable);

        // Boolean mode allows us to match john* for words starting with john
        // (https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/fulltext-boolean.html)
        $query->whereRaw(
            "MATCH ({$columns}) AGAINST (? IN BOOLEAN MODE)",
            $this->buildWildCards($term)
        );
        return $query;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

adding this to my migration solved the issue

```
DB::statement(
   'ALTER TABLE users ADD FULLTEXT fulltext_index(name, email, bio)'
);
```

Answer (score 0):

If u wanna do it without trait, just add this code in your component. And don't forget to add wire:model="search" in your blade file.

```
public $customers, $search, $name, $email, $phone;
public function render()
{
    $query=Customer::latest();
    if($this->search!=''){
        $query->where('name','like','%'.$this->search.'%');
        $query->orWhere('phone','like','%'.$this->search.'%');
        $query->orWhere('email','like','%'.$this->search.'%');
    }
    $this->customers=$query->get();
    return view('livewire.customer-component');
}
```

---